# Inheritance with different template parameters

Tags: c++, inheritance

I would like to know if there is any problem when deriving a class which has an STL container but the templated parameter is different. In other words:

Base class:

```
class GridCell {
    //....
    std::vector<Coord> getNeighbours(const int * coord);
    //....
}
```

Derived classes:

```
class GridCell2D {
    //....
    std::vector<Coord2D> getNeighbours(const int * coord);
    //....
}

class GridCell3D {
    //....
    std::vector<Coord3D> getNeighbours(const int * coord);
    //....
}
```

Will polymorphism work properly with the getNeighbours function? Thank you!

Comment: No.  This will just result in a compilation error (assuming you make the original `virtual` and have things inherit from each other as appropriate).  http://ideone.com/pmddOe.

Comment: The three classes are unrelated types. There is no polymorphism here. Was the intention to derive `GridCell2D` and `GridCell3D` from `GridCell`?

Comment: As long as the return types are covariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this will not work.

You can only inherit functions if the argument list has identical types. Yes that *is* true in your case.

**But** the return types must be related too. Normally they should be the same type but *related* types *are* permitted. Loosely speaking, types are *related* if they are part of the same inheritance heirarchy. But that's not the case here.

Note that to kick off inheritance, you need to mark the function in the base class `virtual`.

Comment: Not to kick off inheritance, but to kick off polymorphism. As written, the inheritance is not a problem. When `GridCell::getNeighbours` is marked `virtual` you get the problem with mismatched return types.

Comment: Well, in my case the argument classes (Coord2D, Coord3D and so on) can be inherited from Coord. Will this work then?

Sorry I forgot the virtual in the base class GridCell. 

The problem of doing that this way is that I am not able to find a better, efficient classes design :S